# putting google travel mode into xml url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml

What I am trying to do is when the travel mode is selected it would put the value into the xml url and provide me the info i need.

This image is the buttons for selecting travel modes for the google api, below the picture is the code for it.

[image]

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" >
        <button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnDrive"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-car"></span></button>
        <button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnWalk"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-wheelchair-alt"></span></button>
        <button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnBike"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bicycle"></span></button>
        <button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="transit" id="btnTransit"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-train"></span></button>
    </div>
```

Below is the url for the xml info. Next to the "mode=" i want to put whatever mode was selected.

```
String GoogleURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&mode=" +  + "&origins=" + txtA.Text + "&destinations=" + txtB.Text + "&key=AIzaSyBApHnE1nXT3lsyS_CZqtXr8j1p0BhpQZA";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           string xml =
                "<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\" >" +
                    "<button runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"btnDrive\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-car\"></span></button>" +
                    "<button runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"btnWalk\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-wheelchair-alt\"></span></button>" +
                    "<button runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"btnBike\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-bicycle\"></span></button>" +
                    "<button runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" value=\"transit\" id=\"btnTransit\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-train\"></span></button>" +
                "</div>";

            XElement button = XElement.Parse(xml);
            string selection = button.Elements("button").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("value") != null).Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault();

            string units = "imperial";
            string mode = string.Format("%22%20+%20{0}%20+%20%22", selection);
            string origin = "%22%20+%20txtA.Text%20+%20%22";
            string destination = "%22%20+%20txtB.Text%20+%20%22";
            string key = "AIzaSyBApHnE1nXT3lsyS_CZqtXr8j1p0BhpQZA";
            string url = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units={0}&mode={1}&origins={2}&destinations={3}&key={4}",
                units, mode, origin, destination, key);
```

Comment: does the div with buttons has to be in a string? @jdweng

Comment: You can use XElement.Load(filename or url)

Comment: i have that code in the aspx file, so do i remove it from there and add do it that way ^?

Comment: You really have html not xml (div tag is html).  You can parse some html with xml but no all.  Some people really frown on using xml on html.  So the correct answer would be to do it in aspx and not c#.